# The URL is getting concatenated

Tags: url, redirect, 404

In my Magento store, the URL of the selected page is getting concatenated with the existing URL that is for example if I am in the URL http://electric.com/ninja and select another option in the menu as switches.

Instead of getting redirected to the URL http://electric.com/switches.html it is getting redirected to the URL http://electric.com/ninja/switches.html by concatenating itself to the previous URL as a result, I am getting the 404 error as the page doesn't exist.

Kindly let me know Why is this happening and how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find my understanding below:

ninja is parent category and swithces is child category, we need to remove ninja from child category URL,

```
Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options.
Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"
Refresh category url index.
```

Comment: yes you got me right and the answer you gave solved the issue. Thank You :)